# ajax error, the data is burried

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is my code

main.js

```
var save_method, table;
//Menerapkan plugin datatables
$(function(){
   table = $('.table').DataTable({
      "processing" : true,
      "ajax" : {
         "url" : "ajax/ajax_user.php?action=table_data",
         "type" : "POST"
      }
   });

});
```

ajax_user.php

```
<?php 

include "../config/database.php";
include "../library/view.php";

if ($_GET['action'] == "table_data") {
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT p.*, v.nama_provinsi, k.nama_kota, j.nama_tagihan FROM pelanggan P 
            INNER JOIN provinsi v ON p.id_provinsi = v.id_provinsi 
            INNER JOIN kota k ON p.id_kota = k.id_kota 
            INNER JOIN jenis_tagihan j ON p.id_jenis_tagihan = j.id_jenis_tagihan 
            ORDER BY p.id DESC");
    $data = array();
    $no = 1;
    while($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $no;
        $row = $p['nama_masjid'];
        $row = $p['nama_pengurus'];
        $row = $p['id_pelanggan'];
        $row = $p['tagihan'];
        $row = $p['nama_provinsi'];
        $row = $p['nama_kota'];
        $row = $p['nama_tagihan'];
        $data[] = $row;
        $no++;
    }

    $output = array("data" => $data);
    echo json_encode($output);
}

 ?>
```

and this is my error

[image]

The last data in the array appears but the previous data disappears what's wrong ?

Comment: Because the array gets overwritten ?

Comment: What’s wrong is that you seem to have no idea how to properly work with arrays ... You create $row as an array inside your loop, and append $no as a new entry. But then you are just starting to _overwrite_ $row with data from individual columns ...

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$data = [];
$i=0;
while($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $data[$i]['nama_masjid']  = $p['nama_masjid'];
    $data[$i]['nama_pengurus']= $p['nama_pengurus'];

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: in datatable not work "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

Comment: and "DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"